# Create a macro for colored versions of "\cmark"

Tags: macros, color

`\cmark` has been defined as follows

```
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
```

I am using the `\textcolor{red}{\cmark}` to show the red tick

How do I make a macro for this?

Answer (score 4):

Include the packages

```
\usepackage{xcolor,pifont}
```

then define the rule as

```
\newcommand*\colourcheck[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1check\endcsname{\textcolor{#1}{\ding{51}}}%
}
\colourcheck{blue}
\colourcheck{green}
\colourcheck{red}
```

Then use as

```
\redcheck
\bluecheck
\greencheck
```

The rule means that `check` will be replaced by something which is `red`, `green` and `blue` in this case.

Comment: To make your answer more readily usable by future readers of this posting, you should provide information about which packages must be loaded for your code to compile successfully. E.g., which package provides the macro called `\ding`, and which package provides the macro called `\textcolor`?